# Proof that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is differentiable function between manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M,N$ differentiable manifolds s.t. $M= \mathbb{R}^2$ and $N= \mathbb{R}^3$ and
$f:M \rightarrow N$ : $f(x,y)=(x,x^2,y^4)$.
Prove that f is differentiable.

**My attempt:**
Suppose $(U,Id_{\mathbb{R}^2})$ chart of $M$ and $(V,Id_{\mathbb{R}^3})$ chart of $N$.
$f$ is differentiable because $h=Id_{\mathbb{R}^3} \circ f \circ Id_{\mathbb{R}^2} : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 :h(x,y)=(x,x^2,y^4) $ is obviously differentiable.

Comment: I guess we don't need any charts here. Polynomials are differentiable.

Comment: It's hard to know what to make of the question without pedagogical context. The aim might be to practice using the definition of _smoothness_ of a mapping, or to recognize that Cartesian spaces with their Euclidean topology are smooth manifolds, or perhaps something else. Absent any motivation, however, the question could be an exercise from _Mathematics Made Difficult_.

Comment: This seems reasonable to me. Instead of "is obviously differentiable" I would probably write something like "each coordinate is a polynomial and therefore differentiable" or some such.

Comment: I don't think using the identity maps actually gets you anywhere, and they just clutter up the language around $f$ itself being differentiable. I think you ought to focus on showing that polynomials are differentiable, and that each of its coordinates are differentiable, or more specifically that $\pi_i\circ f$ is differentiable for $i = 1,~2,~3$, where $\pi_i$ a canonical projection.

Comment: What is the context of this question? Is it an exercise in using the definition of differentiability (existence of a linear map, etc.)?